# Terraform cors problem in AWS: s3+CF api-gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, api-gateway

I have an infrastructure set up in AWS using Terraform that includes several lambda services. These services are accessed through an API gateway from a front end hosted in S3+CloudFront. However, I am experiencing a CORS error. Here is my configuration:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "admin" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.register.id
  path_part   = "admin"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "admin" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
  api_key_required = "false"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "admin" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.admin.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                 = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                  = aws_lambda_function.example_users.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "admin" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.admin.http_method
  status_code = "200"
  
  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "admin" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.admin.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.admin.status_code
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.admin
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "admin_opts" {
    rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
    http_method   = "OPTIONS"
    authorization = "NONE"
    api_key_required = "false"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "admin_opts" {
    rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
    http_method   = aws_api_gateway_method.admin_opts.http_method
    type          = "MOCK"

    depends_on = [
      aws_api_gateway_method.admin_opts
    ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "admin_opts" {
    rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
    http_method   = aws_api_gateway_method.admin_opts.http_method
    status_code   = "200"
    
  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
  
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = true
  }

    depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_method.admin_opts
  ]
  
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "admin_opts" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.admin.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.admin_opts.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.admin_opts.status_code

  response_parameters = {
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS'"
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
    }
  
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_method_response.admin_opts
 ]
}
```

I would really appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup CORS on your Lambda function since you are using the proxy method, for example:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```